# Ansible Register access invocation_module?

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a playbook that downloads a list of files from S3, this list can be set dynamically by utilizing with_items and |default([]).

After pulling this I need to get a list of destinations of the stored files and perform other actions. I registered the var `output` and see that invocation module_args has the value "Dest" which is what i want to access.

I've tried things like:

```yaml
debug: msg="{{ item }}"
with_items: "{{ output.results }}
```

Or even accessing output.invocation but get undefined variable

Task:

```yaml
  - name: "Download Apps from S3"
    aws_s3:
      bucket: "{{ resource_bucket_name }}"
      object: "{{ s3_apps[item].src }}"
      dest: "{{ s3_apps[item].dest }}"
      mode: get
    with_items: "{{ s3_apps_decl |default([]) }}"
    register: output
```

My output variable with debug:

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "aws_access_key": null,
                    "aws_secret_key": null,
                    "bucket": "bucket-resources",
                    "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
                    "dest": "/tmp/test_app.tgz",
                    "dualstack": false,
                    "ec2_url": null,
                    "encrypt": true,
                    "encryption_kms_key_id": null,
                    "encryption_mode": "AES256",
                    "expiry": 600,
                    "headers": null,
                    "ignore_nonexistent_bucket": false,
                    "marker": "",
                    "max_keys": 1000,
                    "metadata": null,
                    "mode": "get",
                    "object": "test_app.tgz",
                    "overwrite": "always",
                    "permission": [
                        "private"
                    ],
                    "prefix": "",
                    "profile": null,
                    "region": null,
                    "retries": 0,
                    "rgw": false,
                    "s3_url": null,
                    "security_token": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "validate_certs": true,
                    "version": null
                }
            },
            "item": "test_app",
            "msg": "GET operation complete"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "aws_access_key": null,
                    "aws_secret_key": null,
                    "bucket": "bucket-resources",
                    "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
                    "dest": "/tmp/testanotherapp.spl",
                    "dualstack": false,
                    "ec2_url": null,
                    "encrypt": true,
                    "encryption_kms_key_id": null,
                    "encryption_mode": "AES256",
                    "expiry": 600,
                    "headers": null,
                    "ignore_nonexistent_bucket": false,
                    "marker": "",
                    "max_keys": 1000,
                    "metadata": null,
                    "mode": "get",
                    "object": "testanotherapp.spl",
                    "overwrite": "always",
                    "permission": [
                        "private"
                    ],
                    "prefix": "",
                    "profile": null,
                    "region": null,
                    "retries": 0,
                    "rgw": false,
                    "s3_url": null,
                    "security_token": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "validate_certs": true,
                    "version": null
                }
            },
            "item": "testanotherapp",
            "msg": "GET operation complete"
        }
    ]
}
```

My expected output would be to define a variable that outputs:
`['/tmp/testanotherapp.spl'.'/tmp/test_app.tgz']`

I've tried set_fact with the similar syntax as my task above however that only saves the last value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should expect in `output` is exactly what you get since you are receiving the [return values from an `aws_s3` module call](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html#return-values) which you are [registering in a `loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop).

Now, if you want to get a list of only paths of all `dest` you have saved on your target host, you have to [extract the corresponding attribute](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) from your data structure.

```yaml
- name: Show a list of dest paths from previous run
  debug:
    msg: "{{ output.results | map(attribute='invocation.module_args.dest') | list }}"
```

Comment: This is exactly it! I tried so many different combos and some similar to this, also couldnt really find this in documentation. But thanks! :)